# How to detect browser language

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, browser, internationalization

I would like to detect browser language and then check if there is a language supported in my system and show them the page in that language.

```
<?php

$supportedLangs = array('en-GB', 'fr', 'de');

$languages = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

foreach($languages as $lang)
{
    if(in_array($lang, $supportedLangs))
    {
        // Set the page locale to the first supported language found
        $page->setLocale($lang);
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

In this way i was able to detect language from the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` function.

**But what if i want to check if there is just one language i need to check for example spanish ?**

I need to check if the browser detect spanish language 'sp' so $supportedLangs is not anymore an array but just a variable containing a constant 'sp', and if this condition is verified i want to set a variable like `$set=hola` else `$set=hello`

How can i do that ?

Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

The language is stored in the following variable

```
     $language = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

You can get the language by adding a substr from 0 to 2.
You'll have for instance = "fr", "en", etc...